# Rails ActiveRecord where clause

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to select `Cars` from database with where clause looking for best DRY approach for my issue.

for example I have this two parameters

```
params[:car_model_id] (int)
params[:transmission_id] (int)
params[:from_date]
params[:to_date]
```

but I dont know which one will be null

```
if params[:car_model_id].nil? && !params[:transmission_id].nil?
    if params[:from_date].nil? && params[:from_date].nil?
        return Car.where(:transmission_id => params[:transmission_id])
    else
        return Car.where(:transmission_id => params[:transmission_id], :date => params[:from_date]..params[:to_date])
    end
elseif !params[:car_model_id].nil? && params[:transmission_id].nil?
    if params[:from_date].nil? && params[:from_date].nil?
        return Car.where(:car_model_id=> params[:car_model_id])
    else
        return Car.where(:car_model_id=> params[:car_model_id], :date => params[:from_date]..params[:to_date])
    end
else
   return Car.where(:car_model_id=> params[:car_model_id], :transmission_id => params[:transmission_id], :date => params[:from_date]..params[:to_date])
end
```

what is best approach to avoid such bad code and check if parameter is nil inline(in `where`)

Comment: Can you show your route settings for this request.

Comment: Which version of Rails are you using?

Comment: Should have added in the tag. Also, please check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do:

```
car_params = params.slice(:car_model_id, :transmission_id).reject{|k, v| v.nil? }
```

and then:

```
Car.where(car_params)
```

**Explanation:** Since, you're checking if the particular key i.e.: `:car_model_id` and `transmission_id` exists in `params`. The above code would be something like this when you have just `:transimission_id` in `params`:

```
Car.where(:transmission_id => '1')
```

or this when you have `:car_model_id` in `params`:

```
Car.where(:car_model_id => '3')
```

or this when you'll have both:

```
Car.where(:transmission_id => '1', :car_model_id => '3')
```

NOTE: This will work only when you have params keys as the column names for which you're trying to run queries for. If you intend to have a different key in `params` which doesn't match with the column name then I'd suggest you change it's key to the column name in controller itself before `slice`.

**UPDATE**: Since, OP has edited his question and introduced more `if.. else` conditions now. One way to go about solving that and to always keep one thing in mind is to have your `user_params` correct values for which you want to run your queries on the model class, here it's `Car`. So, in this case:

```
car_params = params.slice(:car_model_id, :transmission_id).reject{|k, v| v.nil? }
if params[:from_date].present? && params[:from_date].present?
  car_params.merge!(date: params[:from_date]..params[:to_date])
end
```

and then:

```
Car.where(car_params)
```

Comment: Thank you looks good but whats about if i want to check if car_model_id is not equal != or price > params[:price]?

Comment: I didn't understand what you're asking for. You didn't mention anything of that sort in your question. Would have been easier to brainstorm if you'd posted that upfront, too.

Answer (score 0):

> what is best approach to avoid such bad code and check if parameter is
>   nil inline(in where)

Good Question !

I will make implementation with two extra boolean variables (`transmission_id_is_valid` and 
`car_model_id_is_valid`)

```
transmission_id_is_valid = params[:car_model_id].nil? && !params[:transmission_id].nil?
car_model_id_is_valid = !params[:car_model_id].nil? && params[:transmission_id].nil?

if transmission_id_is_valid
   return Car.where(:transmission_id => params[:transmission_id])
elseif car_model_id_is_valid
   return Car.where(:car_model_id=> params[:car_model_id])
....
end
```

I think now is more human readable.

Comment: There is no better way? coz i have 45 parameters my code will become huge and difficult for the machine

Comment: In case this play with route settings.

Comment: get '/api/cars', to: 'cars#index' and im using strong params also

Answer (score 0):

First, I would change this code to `Car` model, and I think there is no need to check if params doesn't exists.

```
# using Rails 4 methods
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.find_by_transmission_id_or_model_id(trasmission_id, model_id)
     if transmission_id
       find_by trasmission_id: trasmission_id
     elsif model_id
       find_by model_id: model_id
     end
  end
end
```

In controller:

```
def action
   car = Car.find_by_transmission_id_or_model_id params[:trasmission_id], params[:car_model_id]
end
```

**edit:**

This code is fine while you have only two parameters. For many conditional parameters, look at  [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) gem.

Comment: And whats about if there is 45 parameters?